# QA Build Automation Mechanism for .NET Project on SVN

Tags: .net, svn, testing, build-automation, assembla

We are working on .NET Windows Application. We were using TFS from the beginning. Now, after [Assembla](http://assembla.com) - an agile wiki project management and collabration tool that provides a repository for source control which is on SVN we are moving from TFS to SVN.

We didn't bother when we started how would we provide (weekly) builds to our QA. But, as we started using Assembla and filling our patches against open Tickets and reassign it to QA. They now need to have a latest build to review the issue and update the status of the ticket. Prior method of testing was we provide them weekly build and updated defects status on [Mercury QC](http://www.gillogley.com/testing_mercury.shtml) to Fixed. Now, there is no more weekly build. They now have to build as they see a ticket has been updated to 'Ready for Test'.

What would you suggest what method should I suggest to automate this build process for our QA so they can generate builds at their side and can quickly review the issue details mentioned in the ticket and marked it Fixed or REOPENED.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JetBrains Teamcity is one continuous integration system you could use to do this.